# how to set button value and kepress in single input field which input field contains tag-it properties

Tags: php, jquery

```
            [<div class="col-md-5">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input" id="formula" name="formula1" placeholder="Enter formula" value="">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input" id="mformula" name="mformula" disabled="true">
        </div>
```

This code is working fine but i need when i click on (+,-,*) operators then its value should be set to input field and also display tag-it property.

[image]

When i click on operator i want that value push into input field and display the property of tag-it. 
For keyup method this code in working fine.But when i click on operator it not push into input field and not show the tag-it property (for auto complete).

```
        $("#plus").click(function () {
          var value = $(this).val();
     $('input[name=formula1]').val(value);


        });


        $(function () {
            $(document).on("keyup", "#formula", function () {
                var val = $(this).val();
               if (val == '+' || val == '-' || val == '*' || val == '/' || val == '(' || val == ')' || val == 'MonthlyAverageOf') {

                var sampleTags = ['/', '*', '-', '+', '(', ')','MonthlyAverageOf'];

                //-------------------------------
                // Minimal
                //-------------------------------
                $('#myTags').tagit();

                //-------------------------------
                // Single field
                //-------------------------------
                $('#formula').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags,
                    // This will make Tag-it submit a single form value, as a comma-delimited field.
                    singleField: true,
                    singleFieldNode: $('#mformula')
                });

                // formula2 is an INPUT element, rather than a UL as in the other 
                // examples, so it automatically defaults to singleField.
                $('#formula2').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Preloading data in markup
                //-------------------------------
                $('#myULTags').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags, // this param is of course optional. it's for autocomplete.
                    // configure the name of the input field (will be submitted with form), default: item[tags]
                    itemName: 'item',
                    fieldName: 'tags'
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Tag events
                //-------------------------------
                var eventTags = $('#eventTags');

                var addEvent = function (text) {
                    $('#events_container').append(text + '<br>');
                };
//alert(eventTags);
                eventTags.tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags,
                    beforeTagAdded: function (evt, ui) {
                        if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                            addEvent('beforeTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                        }
                    },
                    afterTagAdded: function (evt, ui) {
                        if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                            addEvent('afterTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                        }
                    },
                    beforeTagRemoved: function (evt, ui) {
                        addEvent('beforeTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                    },
                    afterTagRemoved: function (evt, ui) {
                        addEvent('afterTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                    },
                    onTagClicked: function (evt, ui) {
                        addEvent('onTagClicked: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                    },
                    onTagExists: function (evt, ui) {
                        addEvent('onTagExists: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.existingTag));
                    }
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Read-only
                //-------------------------------
                $('#readOnlyTags').tagit({
                    readOnly: true
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Tag-it methods
                //-------------------------------
                $('#methodTags').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Allow spaces without quotes.
                //-------------------------------
                $('#allowSpacesTags').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags,
                    allowSpaces: true
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Remove confirmation
                //-------------------------------
                $('#removeConfirmationTags').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags,
                    removeConfirmation: true
                });

            } else {

                var sampleTags = <?php include('auto.php'); ?>;

                //-------------------------------
                // Minimal
                //-------------------------------
                $('#myTags').tagit();

                //-------------------------------
                // Single field
                //-------------------------------
                $('#formula').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags,
                    // This will make Tag-it submit a single form value, as a comma-delimited field.
                    singleField: true,
                    singleFieldNode: $('#mformula')
                });

                // formula2 is an INPUT element, rather than a UL as in the other 
                // examples, so it automatically defaults to singleField.
                $('#formula2').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Preloading data in markup
                //-------------------------------
                $('#myULTags').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags, // this param is of course optional. it's for autocomplete.
                    // configure the name of the input field (will be submitted with form), default: item[tags]
                    itemName: 'item',
                    fieldName: 'tags'
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Tag events
                //-------------------------------
                var eventTags = $('#eventTags');

                var addEvent = function (text) {
                    $('#events_container').append(text + '<br>');
                };

                eventTags.tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags,
                    beforeTagAdded: function (evt, ui) {
                        if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                            addEvent('beforeTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                        }
                    },
                    afterTagAdded: function (evt, ui) {
                        if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                            addEvent('afterTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                        }
                    },
                    beforeTagRemoved: function (evt, ui) {
                        addEvent('beforeTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                    },
                    afterTagRemoved: function (evt, ui) {
                        addEvent('afterTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                    },
                    onTagClicked: function (evt, ui) {
                        addEvent('onTagClicked: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                    },
                    onTagExists: function (evt, ui) {
                        addEvent('onTagExists: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.existingTag));
                    }
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Read-only
                //-------------------------------
                $('#readOnlyTags').tagit({
                    readOnly: true
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Tag-it methods
                //-------------------------------
                $('#methodTags').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Allow spaces without quotes.
                //-------------------------------
                $('#allowSpacesTags').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags,
                    allowSpaces: true
                });

                //-------------------------------
                // Remove confirmation
                //-------------------------------
                $('#removeConfirmationTags').tagit({
                    availableTags: sampleTags,
                    removeConfirmation: true
                });
            }


            });



            var sampleTags =<?php include('auto.php'); ?>;


            //-------------------------------
            // Minimal
            //-------------------------------
            $('#myTags').tagit();

            //-------------------------------
            // Single field
            //-------------------------------
            $('#formula').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags,
                // This will make Tag-it submit a single form value, as a comma-delimited field.
                singleField: true,
                singleFieldNode: $('#mformula')
            });

            // formula2 is an INPUT element, rather than a UL as in the other 
            // examples, so it automatically defaults to singleField.
            $('#formula2').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags
            });

            //-------------------------------
            // Preloading data in markup
            //-------------------------------
            $('#myULTags').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags, // this param is of course optional. it's for autocomplete.
                // configure the name of the input field (will be submitted with form), default: item[tags]
                itemName: 'item',
                fieldName: 'tags'
            });

            //-------------------------------
            // Tag events
            //-------------------------------
            var eventTags = $('#eventTags');

            var addEvent = function (text) {
                $('#events_container').append(text + '<br>');
            };

            eventTags.tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags,
                beforeTagAdded: function (evt, ui) {
                    if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                        addEvent('beforeTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                    }
                },
                afterTagAdded: function (evt, ui) {
                    if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                        addEvent('afterTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                    }
                },
                beforeTagRemoved: function (evt, ui) {
                    addEvent('beforeTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                },
                afterTagRemoved: function (evt, ui) {
                    addEvent('afterTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                },
                onTagClicked: function (evt, ui) {
                    addEvent('onTagClicked: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
                },
                onTagExists: function (evt, ui) {
                    addEvent('onTagExists: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.existingTag));
                }
            });

            //-------------------------------
            // Read-only
            //-------------------------------
            $('#readOnlyTags').tagit({
                readOnly: true
            });

            //-------------------------------
            // Tag-it methods
            //-------------------------------
            $('#methodTags').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags
            });

            //-------------------------------
            // Allow spaces without quotes.
            //-------------------------------
            $('#allowSpacesTags').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags,
                allowSpaces: true
            });

            //-------------------------------
            // Remove confirmation
            //-------------------------------
            $('#removeConfirmationTags').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags,
                removeConfirmation: true
            });

        });
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: When i click on operator i want that value push into input field and display the property of tag-it. How to do this in tag-it ?